# Execute Go program on Arduino Yún

Tags: go, arduino, cross-compiling, mips32, arduino-yun

I would like to run a Go program on the Arduino Yún platform. It features an embedded Linux running on a 32 bit MIPS processor (Atheros AR9331).

Contents of test.go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello!")
}
```

I use the following command on Linux (4.13.12-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Nov 8 11:54:06 CET 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux), Go (go1.9.2 linux/amd64) to compile the binary:

```
GOOS=linux GOARCH=mips go build test.go
```

I copy the binary to the device (via SSH) and execute it there. It doesn't crash. It doesn't print "Hello!". It just seems to wait for stdin. How can I debug/fix this?

Contents of /proc/cpuinfo on the device:

```
system type     : Atheros AR9330 rev 1
machine         : Arduino Yun
processor       : 0
cpu model       : MIPS 24Kc V7.4
BogoMIPS        : 265.42
wait instruction    : yes
microsecond timers  : yes
tlb_entries     : 16
extra interrupt vector  : yes
hardware watchpoint : yes, count: 4, address/irw mask: [0x0000, 0x0920, 0x04b8, 0x0180]
ASEs implemented    : mips16
shadow register sets    : 1
kscratch registers  : 0
core            : 0
VCED exceptions     : not available
VCEI exceptions     : not available
```

Output of strace ./test on the device:

```
execve("./test", ["./test"], [/* 11 vars */]) = 0
```

Output of uname -r on the device:

```
Linux B4218AF03376 3.3.8 #1 Sun Oct 4 02:29:26 CEST 2015 mips GNU/Linux
```

Comment: You can run `strace program` to find out what system call it makes and possibly blocks on.

Comment: I have added the strace output. In a previous version of the question I had indeed uploaded a binary built for the wrong platform.

Comment: What is the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: Do you have floating-point emulation compiled in your linux? I have heard of similar behavior when the device is missing an FPU and does not support floating-point emulation.

Comment: I've added the output of uname -a.

@HeinOldewage How can I check that? I've read that it's enabled by default since kernel 2.2.4, but this may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try again with Go 1.10, which added 32-bit MIPS software floating point emulation.

You can enable this with `GOMIPS=softfloat`, see
https://golang.org/doc/go1.10#ports